# Call a function in a DLL library from another project but in the same solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I am building a solution in visual studio 2019.

There are 2 projects in this solution: TestingRunner2 and TestingDLL2.

In TestingDLL2 I am trying to create my DLL library (one method in my case),
and in TestingRunner2 I am trying to call this method.

This is the general project structure :

[image]

And this is the dllmain.c file content :

```
#include "pch.h"
#define EXPORTING_DLL
#include "dllmain.h"

#include <iostream>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved) {
    switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

void HelloWorld() {
    std::cout << "Hello World !~!~!";
}
```

And finally the dllmain.h content :

```
#ifndef DLLMAIN

#define DLLMAIN

#ifdef EXPORTING_DLL
extern __declspec(dllexport) void HelloWorld();
#else
extern __declspec(dllimport) void HelloWorld();
#endif

#endif
```

What I am actually trying to do is, calling HelloWorld() function from `TestingRunner2.cpp` file.

Are `dllmain.c` and `dllmain.h` content correct?
If yes, what should I write in `TestingRunner2.cpp` in order to achieve my purpose?

Comment: Looks like a mental block, "dllmain.h" is an awfully strange name for a file that needs to be #included in the client app.  Call it hello.h and you'd likely be ahead.

Comment: I think visual studio 2019 by default choose this name.

Comment: @XY: Hans has a point. You now need to write `#include "dllmain.h"` in testingRunner.cpp. That's formally correct but it looks weird. Also, make sure to make the EXE project depend on the DLL project.

Comment: @MSalters How to make the EXE project depend on the DLL project? Because when I write `#include "dllmain.h"` in the top of `TestingRunner2.cpp`, the debugger says that no such file or directory. I think that is the problem.

Comment: First, add your DLL into References of your EXE. Then include your header by specifying its relative name (`#include "../TestingDLL2/dllmain.h"`).

Comment: If you make sure that your dll can be successfully built, there is a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170) in MSDN that explains this problem. The second half of the document explains the steps to link the dll, you could refer to it.